# Leaflet - Selecting multiple geoJSON polygon features using Leaflet-Geoman plugin

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon, geojson, leaflet-geoman

I am creating an application that requires the selection of multiple polygon features from a geoJSON file and highlighting them.

I have managed to accomplish this using the Leaflet-Geoman plugin and attaching the listener map.on('pm:create', and using the latLngBounds of the drawn shape to make the selection from the file using intersects.

However, because I am also using the latLngBounds from the geoJSON features it is selecting features that are outside of the extents of the drawn shape. I am aware that this is due to using latLngBounds, which creates a bounding box using the NorthEast and SouthWest corners of the feature rather than just the geometry of the feature itself.

Is there a way to make the proper selection using the pm:create plugin or is there a better way to go about this?

Below is a snippet of the code that I am using.

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsJEj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the powerful library [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/):
[Turf CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@turf/turf)

```
map.on('pm:create',function (e) {
    if(e.shape == 'Rectangle' || e.shape == "Polygon"){
        geoJsonSelect = e.layer.toGeoJSON();
        var layers = map.pm.getGeomanLayers();
        layers = layers.filter(x => x !== e.layer);
        layers.forEach((layer)=>{
            if(turf.booleanContains(geoJsonSelect,layer.toGeoJSON())){
                console.log("Contains")
            }
        });
        e.layer.remove();
    }
});
```